# MongoDB Dynamically validate field in update

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

I want to know if is possible validate the request from a form before update a record in MongoDB.

Model:

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const Schema =  mongoose.Schema;

const batchSchema = Schema({
  batch_number:{type: String, required: true},
  work_order_id:{ type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'work_orders' ,required: true},
  start_date_time:{type: Date, required: true},
  end_date_time:{type: Date},
  status:{type: String},
  //create_date:{type: Date, default: Date.now}
},
{
  timestamps: true
});

const Batch = module.exports = mongoose.model('batches',batchSchema);
```

My Controller:

```
const mongoose = require("mongoose");
const Batch = require('../../models/production/batch');
const batchController = {};

batchController.index = (callback, limit) => {
  Batch.find(callback).limit(limit)
                      .lean(true)
                      .populate('work_order_id');
};

batchController.show = (id, callback) => {
  var query = {_id: id};
  Batch.findById(query,callback)
        .lean(true)
        .populate('work_order_id');
}

batchController.insert = (batch, callback) => {
  Batch.create(batch,callback);
}

batchController.update = (id, batch, options, callback) => {
  var query = {_id: id};
  var update = batch;
  Batch.findOneAndUpdate(query, update, options, callback);
}

batchController.remove = (id, callback) => {
  var query = {_id: id};
  Batch.remove(query, callback);
}

module.exports = batchController;
```

My Route (Only for update):

```
  app.put('/api/batches/:_id',(req, res) => {
      var id = req.params._id;
      var batch = req.body;
      Batch.update(id, batch,{}, (err, batch) => {
        if (err){
          res.status(500).json({msg:"Error en aplicacion",err});
        }
         res.status(200).json(batch);
      });
  });
```

In the create method the model validate the fields, but in the update, mongoose or mongodb doesn't validate the data.

I don't know if this an error I made in the definition of the model or the controller or this is the normal behavior from mongodb and mongoose.

for the create method I create function to validate the fields:

```
function validation(data){
  let errors = {};

  if (!data.batch_number) errors.batch_number = "No puede ser nulo";
  if (!data.work_order_id) errors.work_order_id = "No puede ser nulo";
  if (!data.start_date_time) errors.start_date_time = "No puede ser nulo";
  if (!data.status) errors.status = "No puede ser nulo";

  if (data.batch_number === '') errors.batch_number = "No puede ser vacio";
  if (data.work_order_id === '') errors.work_order_id = "No puede ser vacio";
  if (data.start_date_time === '') errors.start_date_time = "No puede ser vacio";
  if (data.status === '') errors.status = "No puede ser vacio";

  const isValid = Object.keys(errors).length === 0;
  return {errors, isValid}
}
```

This function works fine in the create, but in the update I want o save only the fields sended in the request, not all the fields.

I don't want to hardcode the validation for the update.

I was reading in the version 4.0 of mongodb there is an option runvalidators. and this option do the validations I need.

I can only use stable version (client requirement), I am using Mongodbd 3.4.2 and mongoose 4.8.3.

there is a way to dynamically validate the field sended in the request body in a update method in mongodb with mongoose.

Comment: you need to make sure all the validations are done at the client side and send the data to server only if it valid. That way you can reduce server processing time.

Comment: @Prasanthchinja: Even you had client validation, you still have server validation all the time. Because your client is not only client which can call your server (ex: Jmeter, Postman ...)

Answer (score 0):

I confused mongoose and mongodb validation methods. Using the option

> runvalidators: true

In the update method I get the validation that I need.

```
batchController.update = (id, batch, options, callback) => {
  var query = {_id: id};
  var update = batch;
  var options = { runValidators: true };
  Batch.findOneAndUpdate(query, update, options, callback);
}
```

Now I want to know If is possible to customize the error message from this type of validations.